# Is it possible to return auth()->user after login with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to return the `auth()->user` after login into Laravel 8. I followed this [tutorial](https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/laravel-8-conditional-login-redirects)  and created a new `LoginResponse.php` file inside my `App/Http/Responses` file with the following.

```php
namespace App\Http\Responses;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;

class LoginResponse implements LoginResponseContract
{
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? new JsonResponse(['user' => $this->user], 200)
            : redirect(config('fortify.home'));
    }
}
```

**In my providers/fortify, I have:**

```php
public function boot()
{
    Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
    Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
    Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
    Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

    // register new LoginResponse
    $this->app->singleton(
        \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterResponse::class,
        \App\Http\Responses\RegisterResponse::class
    );

    // register new LoginResponse
    $this->app->singleton(
        \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse::class,
        \App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse::class
    );
}
```

**Finally, in my authenticatedsessioncontroller.php I have:**

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    return $this->loginPipeline($request)->then(function ($request) {
        $user = Auth::user();
        
        return app(LoginResponse::class, ['user' => $user]);
    });
}
```

However, this gives me a CSRF token mismatch instead of returning the logged in user. What is the correct way to return the just logged in user to my Axios call with Laravel 8?

Comment: I took a different approach:
1. publish fortify's routes.
2. Edit the login route to hit your own AuthenticatedSessionController (which should extend the original vendor/laravel/fortify/src/Http/Controllers/AuthenticatedSessionController.php)
3. Edit the "store" method on your own.
4. Profit